# How do I know whether the data is in cache or not in iOS Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm totally new to Firebase. My iOS app support offline feature as well. And I'm using `Firebase.defaultConfig().persistenceEnabled = true` which described by Firebase doc for iOS.

How do I know whether the data is still in the cache or not. I was searching an answer for this question but couldn't find any.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

if firebase is disconnected, the data should be cached.  Check the firebase connection status with:

```
Firebase *connectedRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/.info/connected"];
[connectedRef observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
  if([snapshot.value boolValue]) {
    NSLog(@"connected");
  } else {
    NSLog(@"not connected");
  }
}];
```

there is more info: 
https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/offline-capabilities.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply @alphonese qi. Actually my problem here is, if I logout using ref.unauth() before the offline  data sync to the firebase server, all the offline data will be lost. Is there anyway I can check my offline data is synced to firebase or not before I unauth() ???

Comment: *firebaser here* There is currently no way for you application code to detect the synchronization state. A workaround is to detect the connection state as @alphoneseqi suggests.

Comment: This is the new link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities